# Hahn Banach application

Tags: functional-analysis

for a linear mapping $T:V\to R$ we have the classic equivalence condition for continuity and boundedness (continuous iff continuous at 0 iff bounded). Could we use the Hahn-Banach theorem to get this result for a semi-norm?

Comment: What kind of result do you want? What fails if you try to mimic the proof of the norm-case and apply it to the semi-norm-case?

Comment: for the bounded implies cts part you need you use $|T(x_n)-T(x)|=|T(x_n-x)|<C|x_n-x|$